# File is getting saved when uploaded 2nd time

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<div class="PriceCalculatorForm">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="PnlSaveData" runat="server">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                     <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Upload Image</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <asp:FileUpload ID="ImageFileUploader" runat="server" />
                         <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-2">
                         <asp:Button ID="btnImageUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Image" OnClick="btnImageUpload_Click" CssClass="btnSearch" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                 </div>
             </asp:Panel>           
         </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
             <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnImageUpload"  />
         </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>

protected void btnImageUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ImageFileUploader.HasFile)
    {
        string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(ImageFileUploader.FileName);

        if (FileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || FileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || FileExtension.ToLower() == ".png" || FileExtension.ToLower() == ".gif")
        {
            string FileName = ImageFileUploader.FileName;

            //Saving the file 
            ImageFileUploader.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + FileName));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Please select file to upload";
        lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

After running code when file is uploaded for first time it goes in else part of code, but the same file when uploaded again it work properly and file is saved at specified location. This is happening every time of execution. I am not getting what is going wrong.

Please any one can guide me on this?

Comment: put it inside the <form> tag.

Comment: It's inside form tag, I have just uploaded part of code

Comment: There is no problem with your code, something else caused this.

Comment: FileUpload control does not work (properly) in update panels. It is well documented.

Comment: @Aria Even I am not getting what's going wrong.

Comment: @GauravBhagwatkar , If you copy these codes in a page you should see there is no problem, I think this is because of `Master` page if you use or something else in `FileUpload` page, How many ScripManager do you have ?

Comment: @Aria , There is just 1 ScriptManager in page, there are multiple <asp:Panel> I have used  but I think its not a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your form tag to this if you are mot using like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
     // your code
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone thank you for your support. Finally I got the solution and end up  by adding `this.Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data"` under `Page_Load` Event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
}
```